# Tests fail when I save (using `--watch` in test script config) but if I re-run manually they pass?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, jestjs

Not a big problem per se but I'm curious as to what's causing this behavior. I'm writing some very basic code to learn how to do some testing. I'm using jestjs for testing a node/express application, and am presently testing the development version of my project locally.  All versions are up to date (most current available).

In the configuration for jest I have the following setup:

```
...
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd -f ./config/test.env jest --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "verbose": true
  }
```

And my environment configuration (as referenced above by the `env-cmd`:

```
PORT=3000
SENDGRID_API_KEY=<API KEY>
JWT_SECRET=<JWT SECRET>
MONGODB_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/task-manager-api-test
```

The `--watch` flag is supposed to work sort of like nodemon - whenever I save my test file it re-runs the tests. The problem seems to be that whenever I save the file some of the tests fail (it's fairly inconsistent as to which tests fail) - but if I manually re-run the tests (`--watch` gives me a CLI that allows me to re-run tests with a keypress) the tests pass.

I'm using the following in my test file to make sure that the DB instance has no data in it before running the tests:

```js
// User to seed DB
const testUserUID = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()

const testUser = {
  _id: testUserUID,
  name: 'firstName lastName',
  email: 'automatedTest@test.com',
  password: 'test1234',
  tokens: [{
    token: jwt.sign({ _id: testUserUID }, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
  }]
}

// Setup
beforeEach(async () => {
  await User.deleteMany()
  await new User(testUser).save()
})
```

An Example of one of my tests:

```js
test('Should signup a user', async () => {
  await request(app)
    .post('/users')
    .send({
      name: 'hardcodeFirst hardcodeLast',
      email: 'hardcodeTest@test.com',
      password: 'test1234'
    })
    .expect(201)
})
```

One of the more common errors I am getting is a MongoError:

```js
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: task-manager-api-test.users index: email_1 dup key: { : "automatedtest@test.com" }
```

The other errors that are being thrown are related to the tests failing - so I'm getting values that the test does not expect.

I've tried googling some stuff related to testing async with jest but I haven't found anything that isn't shown in the documentation about how to use promises or async/await with jest.  I've verified that my environment variables aren't pointing at my remote DB instance.  I've run the tests in my normal (non-vscode) terminal.  I've also verified that the tests always pass when using the `--watch` CLI (pressing `Enter` or `a` repeatedly) - the tests are only failing when I save the test file and it automatically re-runs due to the `--watch` flag.

Talking to one of my developer buddies it was suggested that I've possibly somehow created some sort of race condition. That would be a new situation for me if that's the case!

Thanks in advance for taking a look/any help offered!

EDIT: Included `.env` for my test environment

Answer (score 0):

`--watch` flag works only for  github repos. u should add `watchAll`

```
"test": "env-cmd -f ./config/test.env jest --watch"
```

rest of your code looks fine.

Comment: "--watch flag works only for github repos."

- Could you share, where did you get that info from, please?